# Using an SQLite SELECT with ORDER BY and OFFSET and LIMIT for fast display, BUT HOW do I find the OFFSET of a row WHERE name = x?

Tags: sqlite

Instead of downloading a whole table, we use OFFSET and LIMIT to fetch rows as needed, so we can quickly display large tables.  We can click columns to change SORT BY. When we start, we want to display the row of the last-selected customer using the previous sort string, so we need to find the OFFSET value, which may have changed.

Obviously I can run the SELECT without OFFSET and LIMIT, counting rows until I find name = x.

BUT is there some faster way that sqlite can directly tell me what OFFSET to use on that sorted SELECT for customer x ?

Comment: See https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
SELECT rn
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY columnname) rn
  FROM tablename
)
WHERE name = 'x';
```

Change `columnname` to the name of the column that you use to sort the table and maybe add `DESC` to sort descending.